# How to make paragaph effect after 2 enter or \n?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If you follow the script below, when you enter 1 time. Then it will be a paragraph. How to bring up paragraph after 2 or more enter? Because in the code, there is `\n`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.button').on("click", function() {
    var gogel = $('#mytxtarea').val();

    $('#posttextareadisplay').html(telol(gogel));
  });

  $('#mytxtarea').on("input propertychange", function() {
    var gogel = $('#mytxtarea').val();

    $('#posttextareadisplay').html(telol(gogel));
  });
})

function telol(str) {

  $format_search = [
    /\r\n|\r|\n|\n\r/g,
    /(.*?)\001/g,
    /\[arab\](.*?)\[\/arab\]/ig,
    /\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\]/ig,
    /\[i\](.*?)\[\/i\]/ig,
    /\[u\](.*?)\[\/u\]/ig,
    /\[\*\](.*?)(\n|\r\n?)/ig,
    /\[ul\]/ig, /\[\/ul\]/ig,
    /\[ol\]/ig, /\[\/ol\]/ig,
    /\[url\](.*?)\[\/url\]/ig,
  ];


  $format_replace = [
    '\001',
    '<p>$1</p>',
    '<span class="lbs0">$</span>',
    '<b>$1</b>',
    '<em>$1</em>',
    '<span style="text-decoration: underline;">$1</span>',
    '<li>$1</li>',
    '<ul>', '</ul>',
    '<ol>', '</ol>',
    '<a href="$1">$1</a>',
  ];
  for (var i = 0; i < $format_search.length; i++) {


    var arrText = str.trim().split(/\r|\n|\n\r|\r\n/);
    var newText = '';
    $.each(arrText, function(i, text) {
      if (text.length < 1 || text == "\r\n" || text == "\n" || text == "\r" || text == "\n\r") {
        return true;
      }
      newText += text.trim() + '\n';
    });




    str = newText.replace($format_search[i], $format_replace[i]);
  }
  return str;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <p>
    <textarea name="mytxtarea" id="mytxtarea" class="ed">This is a sample text</textarea>
  </p>
  <p id="posttextareadisplay"></p>
  <p>
  </p>
</form>
```

OR LOGIC like this

A variable passed from PHP as below:

```
 This is man.

 Man like dog.
 Man like to drink.

 Man is the king."
```

I would like my result to look something like this after the Javascript converts it:

```
 This is man<br />Man like dog. Man like to drink.<br />Man is the king."
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It show text on clicking 2 times on the button , by using `$('.button').on('dblclick',function{........});`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.button').on("dblclick", function() {
    var gogel = $('#mytxtarea').val();

    $('#posttextareadisplay').html(telol(gogel));
  });

  $('#mytxtarea').on("input propertychange", function() {
    var gogel = $('#mytxtarea').val();

    $('#posttextareadisplay').html(telol(gogel));
  });
})

function telol(str) {

  $format_search = [
    /\r\n|\r|\n|\n\r/g,
    /(.*?)\001/g,
    /\[arab\](.*?)\[\/arab\]/ig,
    /\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\]/ig,
    /\[i\](.*?)\[\/i\]/ig,
    /\[u\](.*?)\[\/u\]/ig,
    /\[\*\](.*?)(\n|\r\n?)/ig,
    /\[ul\]/ig, /\[\/ul\]/ig,
    /\[ol\]/ig, /\[\/ol\]/ig,
    /\[url\](.*?)\[\/url\]/ig,
  ];


  $format_replace = [
    '\001',
    '<p>$1</p>',
    '<span class="lbs0">$</span>',
    '<b>$1</b>',
    '<em>$1</em>',
    '<span style="text-decoration: underline;">$1</span>',
    '<li>$1</li>',
    '<ul>', '</ul>',
    '<ol>', '</ol>',
    '<a href="$1">$1</a>',
  ];
  for (var i = 0; i < $format_search.length; i++) {


    var arrText = str.trim().split(/\r|\n|\n\r|\r\n/);
    var newText = '';
    $.each(arrText, function(i, text) {
      if (text.length < 1 || text == "\r\n" || text == "\n" || text == "\r" || text == "\n\r") {
        return true;
      }
      newText += text.trim() + '\n';
    });




    str = newText.replace($format_search[i], $format_replace[i]);
  }
  return str;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <p>
    <textarea name="mytxtarea" id="mytxtarea" class="ed">This is a sample text</textarea>
  </p>
  <p id="posttextareadisplay"></p>
  <p>
  </p>
</form>

<button class="button">
click here
</button>
```

Comment: i dont want using click. `This is a sa[enter]mple text` so to be `This is a sa<br>mple text` i need `[enter][enter]`

Comment: Ah ok, so you want to made a programatically enter to skipe lines?

Comment: Yes automatic. Please try the code then enter 1 time. Then it will create a paragraph

Answer (score 0):

In your format search and replace arrays, you're looking for a new line character from any major OS, and then replacing that as /001, which is next converted to a paragraph `<p>` element.

If you want, for instance, a single line break `<br/>` tag when there is only 1 carriage return, you could first look for \n\n (in all forms) and define those as \001, and then go back and look for all single newlines \n and define those as \002.

Then, whenever you see \001, it will be a `<p>` tag as you have it, and whenever you see a \002, it should be converted into a `<br/>`.

```
$format_search = [
  /\r\n\r\n|\r\r|\n\n|\n\r\n\r/g,
  /\r\n|\r|\n|\n\r/g,
  /(.*?)\001/g,
  /(.*?)\002/g,
  ...
];

$format_replace = [
  '\001',
  '\002',
  '<p>$1</p>',
  '$1<br/>',
  ...
];
```